# Identification of SOT 23 component with label 01B and sideways 4

Tags: transistors, identification, surface-mount, sot23

[image: Red arrow pointing to component I'd like identified]

[image]

I have narrowed it down to APR3001/2/3 with datasheet avaialble here: https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/149511/ANPEC/APR3001.html

However, the pinout and datasheet do not make sense to me. In the Markings section of the datasheet, they mention that Package code "B" is for the SOT-23-5 pinout while the component in the picture is clearly SOT-23, but has the Package code "B".

Is my component indeed APR3001 or am I missing something?

Just to put it into a perspective this is a Steelseries Arctis 9 wireless dongle receiver/transmitter PCB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part number is LP2301BLT1G (20V P-Channel Enhancement-Mode MOSFET) see [link for datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811061311_LRC-LP2301BLT1G_C55450.pdf):

[image: 01B SOT23]
https://www.taobao.com/list/item/655095294882.htm

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! How were you able to identify it? Could you also explain why I got it wrong and thought it was APR3001 - they look very similar.

Comment: @Nanyo It's a possibility by marking, but the PCB looks like a MOSFET: pin 1 has an RC to it (pull-up for default off, plus slow rise/fall?), pin 2 seems to be a supply (the 5-pin SOT may be a regulator), and pin 3 seems output (drain). There are too many parts and too few codes to identify SMTs uniquely; this is why context matters.